# Unable to change description for the `RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP` firewall rule via powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2019, windows-firewall, windows-server-core

I'm trying to change RDP port for my Windows Server 2019 Core. I've edited the registry successfully and was able to update the port in firewall rules so that everything works:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP" | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter


Protocol      : TCP
LocalPort     : 3355
RemotePort    : Any
IcmpType      : Any
DynamicTarget : Any



PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP"


Name                  : RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP
DisplayName           : Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)
Description           : Inbound rule for the Remote Desktop service to allow RDP traffic. [TCP 3389]
DisplayGroup          : Remote Desktop
Group                 : @FirewallAPI.dll,-28752
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Any
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local
```

Now I try to change the rule's `Description` correspondingly for clarity:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP" -Description "Inbound rule for the Remote Desktop service to allow RDP traffic. [TCP 3355]"
```

The output is empty and the command apparently does not work:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetFirewallRule -Name "RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP"


Name                  : RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP
DisplayName           : Remote Desktop - User Mode (TCP-In)
Description           : Inbound rule for the Remote Desktop service to allow RDP traffic. [TCP 3389]
DisplayGroup          : Remote Desktop
Group                 : @FirewallAPI.dll,-28752
Enabled               : True
Profile               : Any
Platform              : {}
Direction             : Inbound
Action                : Allow
EdgeTraversalPolicy   : Block
LooseSourceMapping    : False
LocalOnlyMapping      : False
Owner                 :
PrimaryStatus         : OK
Status                : The rule was parsed successfully from the store. (65536)
EnforcementStatus     : NotApplicable
PolicyStoreSource     : PersistentStore
PolicyStoreSourceType : Local
```

Changing description for a manually created rule works.

What is the reason and/or how do I fix this? Should I maybe copy these rules to new rules, fix their description and disable these old rules instead?